# Javascript - parse html string get each element with class X and return array of them

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, parsing

Hi i need to put into a json a huge mass of elements text content using pure Javascript (no jquery), then put them into a json array.

For example from:

```
<li class="asd">1</li>
<li class="asd">2</li>
<li class="asd">3</li>
<li class="asd">4</li>
<li class="asd">5</li>
<li class="asd">6</li>
<li>no</li>
<li>no</li>
<li>no</li>
<li>no</li>
```

i need to return:

```
{[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

So for example i get an html page content via XHR once i got the html page string, how do i parse it and put all the elements with `class="asd"` into a json array?

here is where i get the html string:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
//here i don't know how to parse the html returned :( and put it into a json array
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://site.com/htmlpagecontent.html', true);
    xhr.send(null);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by creating a dummy DOM element and inject your html string into this element. That will create the corresponding node hierarchy, which you can filter with `getElementsByClassName`:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
var nodes = div.getElementsByClassName("asd");
var array = [];
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) { array.push(nodes[i].innerHTML); }
```